Why does it seem Americans care more about "which side" wins elections?
It seems that despite having lower turnouts than many other so-called developed countries, (which has also increased probably as a result of polarization), Americans really care about the outcome of elections.
Another metric that suggests that more Americans care deeply is the completeness of the bifurcation into 2 political parties. In every presidential election since 2004, except for 2016 (which was driven by protest voting rather than identifying with "small parties") 3rd parties were under 3% of the total presidential vote. However, this does not stop Brits, Canadians, and arguably Indians (who also have a first-past-the-post system) from voting for more than 2 political parties.
In the UK and Canada, voters seem far more willing to switch sides. The British parliament shifted massively in 2024 towards Labour, with a lot of the gains ironically driven by Conservative voters moving to a more firmly right-wing party: "Reform UK". What makes this notable is it shows a shift that we simply do not see in American elections. We can also see this in other parts of Europe where far-right parties that were once shunned and formerly received almost no votes are now picking up record vote shares. I focused on the UK as an example because of the electoral system that it uses; which is comparable to the House of Representatives in the US government. However I want this to focus on different countries.
Why does it seem that (among those who vote) Americans care more about "who" wins elections than in other countries? In other words, according to polls, is it true that voters in the US feel like they have more of a "vested interest" in election outcomes compared to most other countries? Is this just true for Canada and the UK (which were chosen because of their electoral systems), or neither?

This is almost certainly going to be closed as opinion-based. That said, US politics has of late taken on an us vs them POV. The two parties used to have a large intersection, where members of one party treated members of the opposing party as opponents. That is no longer the case. The right views the left as mortal enemies, and in response, the left similarly views the right as enemies. While compromise is possible between opponents, mortal enemies must be defeated by any means available. I just received a flyer from a candidate for city council who portrayed his enemy with an ugly CGI image.

I don't think the question is clear enough. What is meant by "care more"? What are those "polls"? And can't it all simply be explained by the voting system which is so particular in the US. On the other hand, I'm sure the French or Japanese or whoever also care about elections.

I had to delete quite a lot of comments. Please remember what comments are for. They are not for attempting to answer the question or for debates unrelated to the question itself.

The US has a presidential system, unlike the UK or Canada (which are parliamentary systems). This means that — in appearance, at least — the US executive branch is 'owned' by one side or the other, with significant policy consequences. This appearance has become more pronounced in recent decades as polarization in Congress has abdicated power to the executive branch, placing the legislative branch in gridlock and encouraging the president to take action through executive orders. 'Which side wins' has become a matter of great concern, since both parties (to differing extents) are trying to secure their divergent agendas through executive fiat, not legislative compromise.
Parliamentary systems are always more subtly attuned. The prime minister (or equivalent) is not independent of the parliament and relies on maintaining consistent support from the other parliamentarians, resulting in a more fluid approach to issues. Citizens in such systems generally feel more empowered because their representative is more empowered and independent, and thus more likely to serve citizen interests. In presidential systems — particularly the two-party system of the US — representatives have a greater incentive to maintain party support than citizen support, and so citizens often feel like a presidential election is an all-or-nothing event in which one side wrests power from the other. It tends to create anxiety…

It tends to create anxiety -- Especially with promises to throw the losers/opposition in jail. I'd somewhat disagree on the issue of party support for MPs. It's more important in the UK actually than in the US. In the US what's important is to not get any big [in money terms] lobby group to fund your counter candidates at some level (primaries or actual election).

Parliamentary systems have just as much gridlock and often end up in stasis (see Belgiums troubles forming a government) or delegating power to unelected judges (see UK’s attempt to enact the Rwanda plan).

@IVFcomesfromthetip: The U.K. allowed the Conservative party to have a leadership challenge over the possible Scottish Independence and Brexit referendums, and had a series of party leaders resign within quick succession, and leading to other people in the party seeking to be the leadership of the party. I think that is closer to what they meant about less incentive towards party support - they can afford to be holding their leaders to account, because they can benefit from it even without an impending election.

"the US executive branch is 'owned' by one side or the other": how is that different from the UK, where the executive has been controlled by either Conservative or Labour for most of the last 80 years? One could argue that things are compounded in a parliamentary system, since the executive - by definition - also controls the legislature.

"representatives have a greater incentive to maintain party support": party discipline is far weaker in the US than in the UK (for example), as if MPs defy their party too much, they face the prospect of being kicked out of the party, and having to stand as an independent at the next election, thereby greatly reducing their chances of being re-elected. My understanding is that this is not true for Congresspeople?

The US and UK are notable for rigid two-party states, compared to somewhere like France or Italy where numerous political parties have come and gone. But I don't think you can correlate two-party states with different degrees of caring or different degrees of extremism. Israel has lots of parties but a very extreme government; most European countries have proportional representation and multiple parties, but still there's a lot of variation in political system and public involvement. In some places like France or Greece public engagement manifests in riots rather than political activity.

@SteveMelnikoff: you're rather correct on the last point. Especially Senators had decent track record of still winning after losing party support. Could make a good Q here actually.

@SteveMelnikoff I've always perceived the Prime Minister in the UK as being more comparable to the Speaker of the House in the United States because the appointment of the Speaker is a decision made by the members of the House of Representatives not the vote of the people (so if the Speaker's party loses the majority they lose their position). In the US, the Speaker of the House is an important person in that they can have A LOT of control over what legislation is even considered, but they can't issue executive orders that compel federal agencies to do things, but the President can.

@Pyrotechnical I see where you're coming from...but it goes further. The PM is head of government, and in that respect combines the power of the Speaker (as head of the party, with control of one house of the legislature) with that of the President (as head of the executive). Because parliamentary systems have a fusion of powers of the legislative and executive branches, the PM is arguably more powerful than the president - because of that control of the legislature - BUT can be removed more easily (e.g. Truss (by her party) in 2022, Callaghan (by the Commons) in 1979).

I think you're on the right track with how much Congress has divested itself of power (which I would argue is unconstitutional at today's scale), but I think you're overselling the ability of a parliamentary system to address the issue. Part of the founders' answer to the problem was the states: the Senate was originally chosen by the state legislatures, not direct election, to give state governments the ability to reign in the popular will. The progressive era where the federal government centralized so much power followed immediately in the wake of switching them to direct election.

@jpmc26: Parliamentary systems have their own problems, no question. I'm not lauding them as intrinsically better, just different.. But we're not talking about 'reining in the popular will' here.  We're talking about factions, as in Federalist #10: coordinated decentralized groups intent on subverting the public will to gain power. We can argue about the effectiveness of the switch to direct election of senators, but we should recognize this switch was made to overcome factional control of the senate.

@jpmc26: Consider a state like Texas, where partisan politics has managed to cast a decidedly purple state as though it were deeply red, with one-party dominance in most positions of political power. Should the federal senators be chosen by the state political apparatus (which is distortedly conservative), or by the citizens of the state (which is ambiguous at best)? It's an issue that ought to be addressed, no?

@TedWrigley Of course not. The people have the House and the President under the original arrangement, and if Texas is purple, this should be reflected in those elections. If the populace is divided in such a manor that the Texas legislature happens to lean one direction even if the popular vote goes another, then having the legislature choose the Senators only further dilutes a narrow majority dominance, as intended. If there's a problem with the way the state government's elections are working, then that needs to be addressed within the state, not by breaking the federal system.

@TedWrigley The US was not created as a democracy. While the founders sought to ensure that the government worked for the good of the populace rather than just political class, they did not see the majority will as fundamental. They saw individual rights as the fundamental principle. Democratic elements are just one tool they tried to use to protect them. Another was the contention between the state and the federal governments, which ceased to exist with direct election of the Senate. This allowed the federal government to steamroll the states, and that has been disastrous for rights.

@TedWrigley "The federal Constitution forms a happy combination in this respect; the great and aggregate interests being referred to the national, the local and particular to the State legislatures." This is what has broken down with direct election of Senators. Over the past hundred years, the federal government has continually inserted itself into more and more local and particular concerns, to the absurd point that it has deemed itself to have authority over any activity that affects goods that cross state lines. It has assumed a role it was never designed to fulfill.

@jpmc26: This isn't the correct place for a debate on the constitution, interesting as that might be. Find a better medium (or move to chat) if you want to continue. I'll merely point out the deceptiveness of worrying about the (ostensible) tyranny of the federal government while ignoring the (actual) tyrannies of the various states. The US constitution was meant to guarantee liberty for the people, not liberty for the states, and most of the 'federal insertions' you'll complain about where designed to protect citizens from the intransigence of their own state governments.


Question:
Why does it seem that (among those who vote) Americans care more about "who" wins elections than in other countries?

I disagree with the premise of the question.
United States Presidential Election Turnout:

2008            61.6%
2012            58.6%
2016            60.1%
2020            66.6%

This turnout compares favorably with the UK and Canada, which for the last 20 years has had turnouts between 40% and 51%.  The US is in line with India's turnout for the last 20 years of 66% 67% and 65.7(2024)%.  Especially after the 2024 turnout is registered.
There is already record turnout for the early voting for the upcoming 2024 United States election.
I think Historically your perspective would be more accurate; however, the strong feelings you are observing in the last few years have lead to much higher turnout.
The current strong feelings as is the higher turnout is directly related to how strongly people feel about at least one candidate in each of the races.  Strongly positive or Strongly negative.  Started With President Obama, Hillary Clinton inspired a lot of emotions, and Donald Trump probable inspires both love and hatred more than anybody.
It's rare for a candidate to loose and election and come back for another go.  Nixon did it in 68 after losing to Kennedey in 1960.  But back to back elections like President Trump is doing has not been done in my lifetime.  To have the non-incumbent candidate suffer two assassination attempts is also unheard of.  So he clearly inspires strong emotions both for and against him.
In the U.S. with our Presidential system voters vote directly for the candidate.  Whereas in a Parliamentary system employed by many of the democracies in your sample group, people vote for the platform, and the party selects its ministers; so personalities might play less a role.

I don't think that Canada/UK are good examples of voter turnout either and those numbers represent presidential election years. When you start talking non presidential years or for non federal elections the voter turnout drops a lot and even a non presidential can be sub 50% if not sub 40% or lower. Non federal elections are even lower. Here is some research that shows the US is still ranked low even in the high turnout years. https://www.pewresearch.org/short-reads/2022/11/01/turnout-in-u-s-has-soared-in-recent-elections-but-by-some-measures-still-trails-that-of-many-other-countries/

Why are you comparing Presidential elections to elections to the European Parliament? Those equate to mid-terms at best. For more relevant UK figures see e.g. https://researchbriefings.files.parliament.uk/documents/CBP-8060/CBP-8060.pdf

@origimbo Did you read the question I answered?  It directly compared presidential election years to elections in parliamentary country’s elections, which I noted in my answer.

@JMS I think the distinction is between the European Parliament (the EU governing body), versus the UK Parliament (the one in London). The European Parliament being less relevant (especially now that the UK has left the EU) to the day-to-day existence of people in Britain than the UK Parliament.
